How to combine datasets for a multimodal biometric system
There are completely different datasets of different people for facial recognition and keyboard dynamics which I need to use.
The idea is that since these datasets contain different users and potentially varying numbers of users, I will need a strategy that allows me to simulate a unified multimodal dataset where each individual is represented across multiple modalities.
Can anyone explain to me how that could be done or point me to a source which could explain the concept, also ensuring that the system is capable of handling variations and not overfitting to a particular group.
Datasets which I’m given are:
Keystrokes
(a) EmoSurv: A typing biometric (Keystroke dynamics) dataset with emotion
labels created using computer keyboards
(b) KeyRecs: Keystroke Dynamics Dataset
(c) Keystroke Dynamics - Benchmark Data Set
Face
(a) IMDB-WIKI – 500k+ face images with age and gender labels
(b) Caltech Face Dataset 1999
(c) Specs on Faces (SoF) Dataset
(d) The Olivetti faces dataset
